# How to have a self instance in a staticmethod in Python

Tags: python, singleton, static-methods

As in the title I want to know how to have a self instance in a staticmethod in python.

Comment: use global keyword I suppose, but I do no think you want to do what your asking...there is a better way

Comment: Why don't you tell us what the problem you're trying to solve is (with code) and we'll suggest something better than using static methods, which are rarely a good idea in Python.

Comment: can you guys see the second answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642500/sending-progress-value-to-progress-bar-in-python/5731192#5731192

Comment: because updating variables in a function as a side effect leads to bugs.  Unless you have to like in C where your dealing directly with memory

Comment: I would do it the same way Mike Ramirez explained.  You need an event/signal based approach.

Comment: @eat_a_lemon I can't do that now because my engine doesn't provide any way for event handling :(

Comment: rewrite it ;)  seriously modifying variables outside of scope is bad practice. It leads to nasty bugs.

Comment: I put an answer on your bounty

Answer (score 6):

By definition, a static method does *not* have a `self` parameter. That's what makes it static. If it did have a `self` parameter, it would be a regular method and not a static method.